# Mysterious: after mov instruction, destination register %rax did not get expected value (in memory)

Tags: linux, multithreading, caching, timer

Life is full of interesting puzzles, wrestling with them makes me cackle ...

---

Recently I get 1 interesting segment fault core dump from running instance x86-64 linux in vm (vmware).

```
mov 0x18(%rdi) %rax // move a pointer to %rax, trick things happens here 
                       it seems rax did not get expected value at all
...// 2 instructions later
mov %r8,0x10(%rax)  // load some value to offset of the pointer in memory
```

### Details below.

```
Segment fault
Dump of assembler code for function timer_delink:
// Function: boolean timer_delink(timer_t　*timer), where timer is a cycle link list(prev/next never NULL)
  0x42e0f0 <+0>:     mov    (%rdi),%rcx                       rdi <= timer; rcx <= timer->parent
  0x42e0f3 <+3>:     xor    %eax,%eax                         eax <= update_parent <= 0; eax stores return value
  0x42e0f5 <+5>:     test   %rcx,%rcx                         if (!timer->parent)  return(FALSE);
  0x42e0f8 <+8>:     je     0x42e138 <timer_delink+72>        return eax(update_parent);
  0x42e0fa <+10>:    mov    0x18(%rdi),%rax                   rax <= timer->prev             //rax should contain timer->prev, which is 
  0x42e0fe <+14>:    mov    0x10(%rdi),%r8                    r8  <= timer->next
  0x42e102 <+18>:    mov    0x8(%rcx),%rdx                    rdx <= timer->parent->down
=>0x42e106 <+22>:    mov    %r8,0x10(%rax)                    timer->rev->next = timer->next;//info register said rax = 0;
  0x42e10a <+26>:    mov    0x10(%rdi),%rsi                   rsi <= timer->next
  0x42e10e <+30>:    mov    %rax,0x18(%rsi)                   timer->next->prev = timer->prev;
  0x42e112 <+34>:    xor    %eax,%eax                         eax <= update_parent <= 0
```

In offending instruction (0x42e106) tries to mov %r8's content to offset 16 from the address contained in %rax, which caused segment fault

Info register said rax = 0, no wonder why segment fault :), But .....

```
  (gdb) info register
  rax            0x0      0       
  ..
  rdi            0x20103ff0       ==> stores timer pointer
```

But per instruction 0x42e0fa, rax should contain timer->prev, which is not 0 per memory dump below

```
(gdb) p *timer
    $8 = {parent = 0x2f379e0 <root_timer>, down = 0x0, next = 0x201027c0, prev = 0x20103b28 ...}
```

So the puzzle is, how could the content of %rax differs from memory on the 3rd instruction after the mov instruction(0x42e0fa)

Could it be cache issue? 
Could it be race condition?

The context of this function call is happen in a ukernel on top of linux and segment fault happens when ukernel is rescheduling the threads.
Only one hardware CPU thread available.

Comment: Show a raw memory dump of `0x20103ff0` of at least 32 bytes.

Comment: It certainly could be a race condition that makes it look like `rax` isn't getting the correct value. For example, if some other thread has modified the timer list afters the instruction at `0x42e0fa` has executed.

Comment: Michael, thank you for the question.

Comment: 0x20103ff0 is actually timer, p *timer has dumped its content, its prev pointer and next pointer contain valid value.        Am also thinking about race condition, but the ukernel runs on a dedicate hardware thread, which means at one time, only one thread can be scheduled .. ..